# Server gets StreamCorruptedException when more than one object received

Tags: java, sockets, stream, server

I'm making a server that's waits for my UserPicture object to come in from a client. When I send one object it works fine. But I get **Errorjava.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7371007E** when I try to send another object from the client.

Here's how I'm waiting for the server to receive the object in a thread:

```
            while(true)
            {
                System.out.println("still waiting for image!");
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                System.out.println("got the image");
                UserPicture usePic = (UserPicture)ois.readObject();
                //do some other work with usePic
            }
```

any ideas why i'm getting this issue?